# How can I prevent JAWS screenreader from reading key strokes?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to test the screenreader dialogue on my application for 508 compliance. It works mostly how it should except a problem I'm running into is when I navigate element to element the screenreader reads each keystroke like so "TAB" when I want to traverse through my application. How can I turn this off while testing? I'm running JAWS 17.

Answer (score 3):

You can't and you shouldn't. Different verbosity settings like functional keys announcement, punctuation reading, repeated characters announcement, treatment of dialog controls and so on, and so forth, — all of these are entirely up to the screen reader and the user who adjusts these settings. Just like, for example, speech rate or pitch. As a JAWS user, I wouldn't be happy, and more than that, I would be angry if some app developer forced me to turn off my `Tab` announcement or changed my punctuation level.

**Update**: If you just want to turn off keystrokes announcement for yourself, do the following:

1. Press *Insert+6* on the number row to go to JAWS Settings Center. You can do this from the JAWS main menu, but the single keystroke is much faster.
2. If you want to make your change by default for all apps, press *Ctrl+Shift+D* to open the default file.
3. In the search box type `labels` and search for Key Labels.
4. In the dialog that appears turn off the announcement for all of the keystrokes you don't want to hear. Note that if you mute *Tab*, all of the keystrokes like *Shift+Tab* and *Ctrl+Tab* will be muted automagically.
5. click OK several times to leave Settings Center and save your settings.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. For TESTING purposes I'd like to eliminate hearing keystrokes. I'm not forcing a user to do anything. These controls are all set by the end user so a developer like myself would not care what the verbosity, speech rate, pitch, etc. is set to on their end. In earlier editions of JAWS I never heard keystrokes, but now I do. It's not as simple as saying "that's just how the screenreader works". It can be adjusted but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Ah OK, sorry then, I thought you would need to eliminate those for all of your users. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a user setting options.
If you do that in your jaws, it's coild bé different for an other person !